# Mongoose with Typescript: Trying to split schema, methods and statics in seperate files, problem with this has type any and is hidden by container

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

i'm trying to split up my single-files mongoose schemas with statics and methods.
(I found this tutorial for splitting: https://medium.com/swlh/using-typescript-with-mongodb-393caf7adfef ) I'm new to typescript but love the benefits it gives while coding.
I've splitted my user.ts into:

- user.schema.ts
- user.model.ts
- user.types.ts
- user.statics.ts
- user.methods.ts

When i change this lines in my schema file:

```
UserSchema.statics.findUserForSignIn = async function findUserForSignIn(
  email: string
): Promise<IUserDocument | null> {
  const user = await this.findOne({ email: email });
  if (!user) {
    return user;
  } else {
    return user;
  }
}
```

to `UserSchema.statics.findUserForSignIn = findUserForSignIn;`

and copy the Function findUserForSignIn to user.statics.ts, Typescript says "'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation" and "An outer value of 'this' is shadowed by this container."

So, how to add this properly? If i add this to findUserForSignIn with IUserModel as Type, add null to Promise return type it would nearly work:

```
export async function findUserForSignIn(
  this: IUserModel,
  email: string
): Promise<IUserDocument | null> {
  const user = await this.findOne({ "person.email": email });
  return user;
}
```

And if i add this to receiving function parameters: users gets to type IUserDocument, before it was any. I think its nice to have typeclear, not just any.

But: in user.schema.ts the UserSchema.statics.findUserForSignIn gets a red line from typescript.  Type can not be assigned to other type. The signature of this is not identical.

If i change the type of this to any, all is okay. But the return is not longer from type IUserDocument. Mabye its okay if i get over an aggregation pipeline and only set the Promise-Return-Type. But that this: any gets hinted in yellow by typescript.

And, another question: if i pass this as first and email as second parameter, why is only one parameter required?

Anyone has an "how to" for me? Or can explain what i've done wrong? Or what is the best way? Or is it not possible to split statics and methods in seperate files from schema?

**Original files:**

user.schema.ts

```
import { Schema } from "mongoose";
import { PersonSchema } from "./person.schema";
import { findUserForSignIn } from "./user.statics";
import { IUserDocument } from "./user.types";

const UserSchema = new Schema<IUserDocument>({
    firstname: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    lastname: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
});

UserSchema.statics.findUserForSignIn = findUserForSignIn;

export default UserSchema;
```

user.types.ts

```
import { Document, Model } from "mongoose";
import { IPerson } from "./person.types";

export interface IUser {
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
    email: string;
}

export interface IUserDocument extends IUser, Document {}
export interface IUserModel extends Model<IUserDocument> {
  findUserForSignIn: (email: string) => Promise<IUserDocument>;
}
```

user.model.ts

```
import { model } from "mongoose";
import UserSchema from "./user.schema";
import { IUserDocument, IUserModel } from "./user.types";

const User = model<IUserDocument>("User", UserSchema) as IUserModel;

export default User;
```

user.statics.ts

```
import { IUserDocument } from "./user.types";

export async function findUserForSignIn(
  email: string
): Promise<IUserDocument | null> {
  const user = await this.findOne({ email: email });
  if (!user) {
    return user;
  } else {
    return user;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way seems to change the user.statics.ts

```
export async function findUserForSignIn(
  this: Model<IUserDocument>,
  email: string
): Promise<IUserDocument | null> {
  console.log("E-Mail", email);
  const user = await this.findOne({ email: email });
  return user;
}
```

this has to be of type Model

Then code seems to be okay.